# Collision detection working weirdly in Arkanoid style game

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna, collision-detection

This is my code for the ball collision in arkanoid:

```
Rectangle intersection = Rectangle.Intersect(block.Rect2D, ball.BallRec);

if (intersection.Width > intersection.Height)
{
    ball.yVel = -ball.yVel;
}
else if (intersection.Width < intersection.Height)
{
    ball.xVel = -ball.xVel;
}
else
{
    ball.xVel = -ball.xVel;
    ball.yVel = -ball.yVel;
}
```

Unfortunately the ball sometimes "melts" into the blocks and bounces weirdly, especially when its at higher speed. How can I fix that?

Comment: When you say "melts" do you mean that the ball is partially inside the block before it bounces? Does it slow down drastically while it is melting?

Comment: If the ball is moving more than 1 pixel (say 10 pixels) at a time, then the intersection could be as much as 9 pixels of overlap. That would explain the "melt". You may need to perform your collision detection on where the ball will be in the next frame, not in the current frame.

Comment: To add to @Pete's comments, even then you may miss collisions if the movement moves it too far, i.e. the ball moves the entire way through the block in a single frame. In which case you will need to increase the frame rate to prevent this (or perform collision detection on sub-frames).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Arkanoid ball acts weirdly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14864135/arkanoid-ball-acts-weirdly)

Comment: @PaulRuane how do I perform collision detection on every frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When collision is detected it is not sufficient to just change the direction of the ball, you need to change the position too. If the ball moved 20 pixels, and is now 5 pixels into the block, then you need to move the ball 5 pixels away from the block.

You will also need to check if the block you are detecting collisions for was *between* the ball's old location and the new one.